# К какому элементу применять transition на scss?

Tags: css-animation, scss

[image: button]

На странице есть такая кнопка, по факту это ссылка внутри которой есть картинка(стрелка), задумка анимации в том что при наведении на ссылку картинка пропадает а текст плавно становится по центру ссылки. Не могу понять как это анимировать, знаю только transition, но не знаю толком как его применить, как это анимировать подскажите пожалуйста

```css
.services__blocks__content-button{
    width: 187px;
    height: 57px;
    margin: auto;
    a{
     display: block;
     text-align: center;
     background-color: $buttonCol;
     border-radius: 30px; 
     width: 187px;
     height: 57px;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-family: $fontRoboto;
     font-size: 18px;
     line-height: 57px;
     color: #FFFFFF;
     img{
      margin-left: 4px;
      width: 24px;
      height: 8px;
     }
     &:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
      img{
       display: none;
      }
     }
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Единственное, что для такого подхода необходимо задать - размер кнопки. Иначе всё будет плавать в стороны:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&display=swap");
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  background-color: #008bff;
  padding: 1.25rem 2rem;
  border-radius: 1.75rem;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
}
.btn span {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
.btn:after {
  flex: 0 20px;
  width: 20px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .3s, flex .3s, width .3s;
  text-align: center;
  content: ">";
}
.btn:hover:after {
  flex: 0;
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: opacity .3s, flex .3s, width .3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
 <a href="#" class="btn">
  <span>Book a free Consultation call</span>
 </a>
</div>
```